# How to answer question on moving to another country for job?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment

I live in country X and recently I had applied to a few exciting job opportunities as a software developer in various organisations in country Y.

Just this week, two of them called for a phone interview and one question that was common in both was: Why do you want to move from country X to country Y to take on this role?

Personally, my answer would be obviously due to the package being offered is way more than what the current market would offer in country X and also much better opportunities to work on bigger projects. But I want to know how I can rephrase this answer in such a way that it doesn't seem to the recruiter that I'm desperate to get out of country X for a job in country Y and also make me stand out as one of the international candidates.

Would love to hear from you guys on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations on your interviews!

You provided the perfect answer to your own question...

> better opportunities to work on bigger projects

Perfect statement. It conveys interest in personal/professional growth and greater responsibility (via larger projects).

It can also convey curiosity and willingness to take risks. Not everyone is willing to leave "home" and familiarity.

If you are looking for more, look at the individual companies you have applied to. There must be something that is uniquely appealing, a little well placed (honest) knowledge/flattery in regard to the company's history, business growth and or area of expertise is always good fodder for greater conversation.